# Docker image works, Kubernetes Pod not working. Ubuntu. Log: /bin/sh: [npm,start]: not found

Tags: docker, npm, kubernetes, kubectl, microk8s

I'm taking a course that uses Kubernetes and am running into an error when I try to create a pod in Kubernetes.

I'm using **Ubuntu**, AMD64

I installed **microk8s.kubectl** following these instructions (https://ubuntu.com/kubernetes/install)

Here's my **Dockerfile** which runs correctly when I use only Docker.

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY ./ ./

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Here's my **posts.yaml** file, verbatim to the course I'm taking

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: posts
spec:
  containers:
    - name: posts
      image: emendoza1986/blog_posts:0.0.1
```

output from ***kubectl get pods***

```
NAME    READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
posts   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6          10m
```

output from ***kubectl logs posts***

```
/bin/sh: [npm,start]: not found
```

output from ***kubectl describe pod posts***

```
Name:         posts
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         desktope/192.168.0.18
Start Time:   Thu, 23 Jul 2020 10:58:40 -0700
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  Status:  Running
IP:           10.1.87.20
IPs:
  IP:  10.1.87.20
Containers:
  posts:
    Container ID:   containerd://acb403c53759670370959cfa2cc0939f53126aee889e1f6dc2e831bc4dc22c3c
    Image:          emendoza1986/blog_posts:0.0.1
    Image ID:       docker.io/emendoza1986/blog_posts@sha256:f69b30cf0382d4c273643ac11c505378854b966063974cc57d187718cc0b0fd5
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    127
      Started:      Thu, 23 Jul 2020 10:58:59 -0700
      Finished:     Thu, 23 Jul 2020 10:58:59 -0700
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  2
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-2fm2c (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-2fm2c:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-2fm2c
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  48s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/posts to desktope
  Normal   Pulled     29s (x3 over 47s)  kubelet, desktope  Container image "emendoza1986/blog_posts:0.0.1" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    29s (x3 over 47s)  kubelet, desktope  Created container posts
  Normal   Started    29s (x3 over 47s)  kubelet, desktope  Started container posts
  Warning  BackOff    12s (x4 over 45s)  kubelet, desktope  Back-off restarting failed container
```

output from ***microk8s.status***

```
microk8s is running
addons:
dashboard: enabled
dns: enabled
metrics-server: enabled
cilium: disabled
fluentd: disabled
gpu: disabled
helm: disabled
helm3: disabled
host-access: disabled
ingress: disabled
istio: disabled
jaeger: disabled
knative: disabled
kubeflow: disabled
linkerd: disabled
metallb: disabled
prometheus: disabled
rbac: disabled
registry: disabled
storage: disabled
```

output from ***microk8s inspect***

```
Inspecting Certificates
Inspecting services
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-cluster-agent is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-containerd is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-apiserver is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-apiserver-kicker is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-proxy is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelet is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-scheduler is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-controller-manager is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-flanneld is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-etcd is running
  Copy service arguments to the final report tarball
Inspecting AppArmor configuration
Gathering system information
  Copy processes list to the final report tarball
  Copy snap list to the final report tarball
  Copy VM name (or none) to the final report tarball
  Copy disk usage information to the final report tarball
  Copy memory usage information to the final report tarball
  Copy server uptime to the final report tarball
  Copy current linux distribution to the final report tarball
  Copy openSSL information to the final report tarball
  Copy network configuration to the final report tarball
Inspecting kubernetes cluster
  Inspect kubernetes cluster

Building the report tarball
  Report tarball is at /var/snap/microk8s/1503/inspection-report-20200723_112646.tar.gz
```

I see the error coming from the log but I haven't been able to find a solution. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Won't be treated as a list unless it parses as JSON

Comment: Quotes are important. Needs to be `["npm", "start"]`; the error message implies that the actual value differs. Make sure it's using real ASCII quotes rather than curly "smart" ones, etc. Or don't try to pass it as JSON at all and switch to `CMD npm start`

Comment: i posted my Dockerfile. Does it look correct?

Comment: You have posted example that works. Your actual setup must be different. Your actual Dockerfile and the one here, they probably differ.

Comment: THank you, I originally had it as ['npm', 'start'] on my docker hub, I corrected my local version but not my docker hub version. That fixed it.

Comment: Make sure that you are pulling the correct image. Since you are not using `latest` tag, if you have pushed image into the same tag, kubernetes will not pull the new image by default

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the helpful comments. Originally I had my Dockerfile as
**CMD ['npm', 'start']**.
I had fixed it locally to
**CMD ["npm", "start"]**
but I didn't push the new version to docker hub.
Pushing the new version fixed the problem.